# .NET from largest to smallest

Tags: c#, .net

I want to sort an array from smallest to largest in .NET (c#) without using Bubble Sort and without using Datatables.Can anyone help me how to complete the task?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //int[,] myArray = new int[4, 2];


            //int[,] array_sorted = { { 20, 9, }, { 75, 25 }, { 90, 78, } };
            int[,] array_sorted = { { 20, 9, }, { 75, 25 }, { 50, 92 }, { 9, 7 }, { 19, 78 }, { 50, 78 }, { 50, 98 }, { 23, 32 }, { 12, 232 }, { 45, 65 } };



            Console.WriteLine("Before Bubble Sorting....");
            for (int i = 0; i < array_sorted.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array_sorted.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,3}", array_sorted[i, j]); // respresent how the element should be represented
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("After Bubble Sorting...");

            for (int i = 0; i < array_sorted.GetLength(0); i++) // Array Sorting
            {
                for (int j = array_sorted.GetLength(1) - 1; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                    {
                        if (array_sorted[i, k] > array_sorted[i, k + 1])
                        {
                            int temp = array_sorted[i, k];
                            array_sorted[i, k] = array_sorted[i, k + 1];
                            array_sorted[i, k + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array_sorted.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array_sorted.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0 ,3}", array_sorted[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }






            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems you might be missing someting in third loop

Comment: Is this homework? You may want to search for sorting algorithms. Quick sort is a very popular general purpose algorithm.

Comment: Are these two arrays which require sorting?

Comment: What version of .Net framework are you targeting?

Comment: @PaulRuane no this is not homework,i am preparing for my interview.I want to do this through bubble sort

Comment: @sixlettervariables,the 2D array at the top

Comment: your question says WITHOUT bubble sort, now you say with. Last time I do a bubble sort was at school as well, and if an interviwer asked me for the .net code for one, I'd just get up and walk out.

Answer (score 2):

Use String.Sort and implement IComparer. You don't have to get this complicated. array.Sort(new YourComparer()). Read upon MSDN array sort and IComparer.

Answer (score 2):

-1 for obvious homework.

Anyhow, here is an easy answer:

var sorted = array.OrderByDesc (x => x).ToArray ();

finished. Untested, so a grammar error may be in. Uses LINQ which is valid according to C# which you give as language.

Comment: The OP's array is 2-dimensional so `OrderByDescending` won't apply in your example.

Comment: I dont want to use build in function

Comment: @ZainShah120: Well, frankly ,. it does not say so - and then it is homework.

Comment: @ZainShah120:Your last two sentences are a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @TomTom Thank you for kind support.i am preparing for my Interview and this type of questions are asked

Comment: @ZainShah120 - Please take this to heart.  The fact you are even asking this question proves you a complete lack of understanding on the subject.  Your earlier comments say you want to implement a bubble sort solution, but the actually question, says you want to avoid a bubble solution.  Please make up your mind, open a NEW question, and share with us what you have attempted to do on your own.  You are never going to get a job if we hold your hand.

Comment: @Ramhound i had mistakenly added without Bubble sort

Comment: Well withdraw this one. Ask for specific help with your Bubble sort implementation, and say you are using sort algorithms as a learning exercise for c#. Adn if your interviewer asks you how you would implement bubble sort in C#. The correct answer is you wouldn't, because .net comes with much efficient algorithms built in.